# Blended Data sources

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau and was using blended datasources for showing values in the sheet. However I ran into a problem. While I am trying to get the date fields from one datasource which is blended into the ward code of another data source. I am trying to show the occupancy values in different dates. However, all I am getting is the sum of the values in the below field like so?
[image]

How can I change this to show different bed occupancy in different dates?

Instead of one number it should be filled with various smaller numbers from different fields

Can anyone give me an idea as to why this is happening. On doing joins I do the same thing and we get the values. However the numbers get fudged

Comment: Can you please make your question more precise?

Comment: the bed occupancy is the same for all values .  i want to show different values based  on the date

Comment: You need to blend the date fields so Tableau knows which dates each value belongs to

Comment: what do you mean by blend date fields

Comment: The other table does not have a date field can we not match it by any other value like ward code for it to work?

Comment: If the other table does not contain a date field that you can also blend to, then the only result you can get back is the total. How would tableau know the appropriate date to use when the date does not exist?

Comment: You please also upload screenshots of datasets to be blended, in order to understand it well

Comment: Hii Anil do you have an answer for this or not . I can upload the screenshots but will you be able to help or just comment